# mod_rewrite rewriting a url

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, apache2

Hay, can someone lend a helping hand to get a rewrite rule to work?

I'm developing a CMS and the URL currently look like this

```
page.php?id=2/About-us
```

I want to remove the

```
page.php?id=2/
```

part of the URL and just show

```
About-us
```

Any ideas how to get this working?

**EDIT**

I have since changed my URLS to

```
page/PAGE_NAME
```

and used the rule

```
RewriteRule ^page/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

However, apache just says that index.php was not found on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure it is `index.php` and not `page.php`?

Please try

```
RewriteRule ^/page/([^/]+)$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

If you need a permanent move

```
RewriteRule ^/page/([^/]+)$ /index.php?page=$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: With the first rule, if i go to /page/Treatments it gives a 404. If i remove the leading / it says index.php was not found (404)